# How to disambiguate a foreach loop in Xcode with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a hexagon grid using swiftUI on Xcode. To loop over the creation of the individual hexagons I am using a foreach loop. However I came Across an error when creating a function that creates a column of hexagons:

```
private func makeCol(C: Int, Bump:Int) -> some View {
        return ZStack {
            ForEach(-5...5, id: \.self) {Ynumber in                
                self.hexagon(
                    x: (ThreeRooted * self.L * Double(C)) + self.centerWidth,
                    y: (ThreeRooted * self.L * Double(Ynumber)) + self.centerHeight + (ThreeRootedOverTwo * self.L * Bump))
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: CGFloat(self.L/4.0))
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

To get around this I extracted my location fields in separate variables. However, this gave another error:

```
private func makeCol(C: Int, Bump:Int) -> some View {
        return ZStack {
            ForEach(-5...5, id: \.self) {Ynumber in
                let xPlot = (ThreeRooted * self.L * Double(C)) + self.centerWidth
                let yPlot = (ThreeRooted * self.L * Double(Ynumber)) + self.centerHeight + (ThreeRootedOverTwo * self.L * Bump)

                self.hexagon(
                    x: xPlot,
                    y: yPlot)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: CGFloat(self.L/4.0))
            }
        }
    }
```

Error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate.

How do I give this loop an *explicit type*?

Comment: You generally can't declare variables/let constants  in a `ForEach`.

Comment: @RobNapier "It is usually best to assume that the diagnostic messages you get around SwiftUI are meaningless" But I wouldn't advise promulgating that as a rule of thumb; Swift 5.2 promises vast improvements and let's see if it delivers.

Comment: what is the return type of hexagon(..) function?

Comment: @Sweeper, try this one (with breaks in needed place, because format of comment does not allow them):  `ForEach(0 ..< 100) { (i) -> Text in
                let a = 1
                return Text("Item \(i + a)")
            }`

Comment: @Asperi I said “generally”...

Comment: hexagon() function currently returns a path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ForEach is a structure** that computes views on demand from an underlying collection of identified data, **NOT a loop**.

How to create hexagonal grid? Below is one possible approach where I tried to show you how to use `ForEach` and SwiftUI declarative syntax.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Hexagon: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { (path) in
            path.move(to: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: (rect.minY + rect.midY) / 2 ))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.maxX, y: (rect.maxY + rect.midY) / 2 ))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: (rect.maxY + rect.midY) / 2 ))
            path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.minX, y: (rect.minY + rect.midY) / 2 ))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: -10) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { j in
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 4) { i in
                        Hexagon()
                            .fill(Color.yellow)
                            .overlay(
                                Hexagon()
                                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
                            )
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 60)
                    }
                }
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3) { i in
                        Hexagon()
                            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 5)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 60)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and here is the result
[image]

Spacing and frame parameters are fixed here for simplicity, you are better to calculate proper numbers.

```
init(Range<Int>, content: (Int) -> Content)
```

> Available when Data is Range, ID is Int, and Content conforms to
>   View.

You tried to use

```
init(Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: (Data.Element) -> Content)
```

> Available when Content conforms to View.

and finally we don't have any idea what type returns your hexagon function, it could be Shape, but Shape is protocol, and that could make your trouble. If it is Shape, try define return type as some Shape.

Yes, compiler **error reporting is still not very usable with SwiftUI**

Answer (score 0):

> How do I give this loop an explicit type?

```
ForEach(-5...5, id: \.self) { (Ynumber) -> _ExplicitType_ in
  ...
  return self.hexagon(
            ...
         )
}
```

Comment: you better to explain him, that ForEach is a structure that computes views on demand from an underlying collection of identified data, NOT a loop.