# How to use variable inside the body of the view using swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

i'm trying to using a variable and modify inside the foreach of swiftui.

below are the code i'm using. please let me know how can i modify the value inside the body of the view.

```
struct SearchView : View {
var chatmember = ChatMember(with: JSON())

var body: some View{
    VStack(spacing: 10){
        VStack{
            prefView()
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            Text("Tap to start making friend")
        }
        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(userDataList) { user in
                     chatmember = ChatMember(hashValue: 0, email: "", fullName: "", online: "", userId: user.userId, userImage: "", deviceToken: "", deviceType: .iOS, deviceId: "")
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(chatMember: self.chatmember)){
                        SearchUser()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
        })
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)

        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Profile",displayMode: .inline)
    .onAppear {
        self.userList()
    }
}


@State var userDataList = [UserModel]()
func userList() {
    databaseReference.child(DatabaseNode.Users.root.rawValue).observe(.value) { (snapShot) in
        if snapShot.exists(){

            if let friendsDictionary = snapShot.value{

                for each in friendsDictionary as! [String : AnyObject]{
                    print(each)
                    if let user = each.value as? [String : Any]{
                        let data = UserModel(userId: JSON(user["userId"] ?? "").stringValue, name: JSON(user["name"] ?? "").stringValue)
                        print(data)
                        self.userDataList.append(data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

below are the error message i'm getting:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'
```

But this error message is not look correct for me. this error i'm getting because i tried to modify chatmember inside of foreach.

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230457/how-to-disambiguate-a-foreach-loop-in-xcode-with-swiftui/60232370#60232370

Comment: How did you manage to get the current user element outside the body? I am new to SwiftUI and couldn't figure it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the `chatmember` in your body function, it should be done in an action clouser or outside of the body function scope.

for populate your `chatmember` you can try this:

add `.onAppear` to your destination and set your chatmember

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(chatMember: self.chatmember).onAppear {
                     chatmember = ChatMember(hashValue: 0, email: "", fullName: "", online: "", userId: user.userId, userImage: "", deviceToken: "", deviceType: .iOS, deviceId: "")
                    }){
                        SearchUser()

don't forget to set your `chatmember` to @State
```

Comment: can you give an example for the same?

Comment: you can define a function and make your list in your function. for your struct define init() and call your function in it

Comment: can you please help me coding example. i want to modify the value and pass it to new view like previously we did in 'did select for row' when we tap on cell item. something  similar to that i want to do that. please help me with coding example i'm new to swiftUI

Comment: Thanks i will implement this and check it. can you please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250383/horizontal-scrollview-is-not-working-swiftui

Comment: value is not reflecting to my chat view. it's not working