# Horizontal scrollview is not working swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, horizontalscrollview, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

i'm trying to show some horizontal view but it's not working. below are the code i'm using.

```
@State var userDataList = [UserModel]()
    var body: some View{
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                VStack{
                    prefView()
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                    Text("Tap to start making friend")
                }
                ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(userDataList) { user in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(chatMember: self.chatmember, user: user)){
                                SearchUser()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                })
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 400)

            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Profile",displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            self.userList()
        }
    }
```

But if i change the above code with below than it work i don't know how please help me.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..< 2) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(chatMember: self.chatmember, user: user)){
                            SearchUser()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            })
```

Thanks in advance