# How to pass variables functions in forEach loops

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

### Goal:

I am currently working on some code to create a grid of hexagons, each one individually coloured with a gradient. However I am quite new to swiftUI and don't fully understand why my code doesn't work.

### Code:

```
ForEach(0 ..< 11, id: \.self) { Xnum in
    ForEach(0 ..< 11, id: \.self) { Ynum in
        self.MyNewPath(in: CGRect(), Xcoord: Double(Xnum), Ycoord: Double(Ynum), Type: 1)
            .fill(RadialGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]),
                center: .init(
                    x: self.gradientParametersX(Xpos: Double(Xnum)),
                    y: self.gradientParametersY(Ypos: Double(Ynum), Xpos: Double(Xnum))),
                startRadius: CGFloat(2.0),
                endRadius: CGFloat(70.0)))
            .gesture(
                TapGesture().onEnded {_ in
                    self.dataEditor(Xplace: Int(Xnum), Yplace: Int(Ynum))
                }
            )
    }
}
```

### Return Types:

- `MyNewPath()` - `Path` (of a hexagon)
- `gradientParametersY()` - `CGFloat`
- `gradientParametersY()` - `CGFloat`

### Error:

*The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions*

The error appears to be centred around the passing of `Xnum` and `Ynum` to functions `gradientParametersX()` and `gradientParametersY()`.

When I pass 7.0 and 0.0 for example:

```
x: self.gradientParametersX(Xpos: Double(7.0)),
y: self.gradientParametersY(Ypos: Double(0.0), Xpos: Double(7.0))),
```

...there is no error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230457/how-to-disambiguate-a-foreach-loop-in-xcode-with-swiftui/60232370#60232370 how to make a hexagonal grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to separate grid item creation in separate function as below (the code snapshot is not testable, so just scratchy to demo idea)

```
    ...
    ForEach(0 ..< 11, id: \.self) { Xnum in
        ForEach(0 ..< 11, id: \.self) { Ynum in
            self.createItem(for: Xnum, Ynum: Ynum)
        }
    }
    ...

private func createItem(for Xnum: Int, Ynum: Int) -> some View {
    self.MyNewPath(in: CGRect(), Xcoord: Double(Xnum), Ycoord: Double(Ynum), Type: 1)
        .fill(RadialGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]),
            center: .init(
                x: self.gradientParametersX(Xpos: Double(Xnum)),
                y: self.gradientParametersY(Ypos: Double(Ynum), Xpos: Double(Xnum))),
            startRadius: CGFloat(2.0),
            endRadius: CGFloat(70.0)))
        .gesture(
            TapGesture().onEnded {_ in
                self.dataEditor(Xplace: Int(Xnum), Yplace: Int(Ynum))
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Asperi this answer is perfect. However, I am still confused as to _why_ the compilator has trouble deducing the types of Xnum and Ynum.

Comment: ![Here is the finished hexagon.](https://imgur.com/a/dQL1zLU)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** Does your answer concerns SwiftUI and not just Swift ? If yes, please edit your question, and see user3441734 comment under it.

---

The compilator seems to have troubles deducing the types of `Xnum` and `Ynum`.
You might have to explicitly write their type.

Your ForEach syntax seems quite weird, have you tried

```
for Xnum:Int in 0..<11
{
    for Ynum:Int in 0..<11
    {

    }
}
```

And then casting `Xnum` and `Ynum` to `Double` ?

You can also directly do a foreach on doubles this way :

```
for Xnum:Double in stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 1.0)
{
    for Ynum:Double in stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 1.0)
    {

    }
}
```