# How to create hexagonal tessellation with custom shapes in SwiftUI (Honey comb grid)

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes, swiftui-list

I am trying to create a [**tessellation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) using a shape created from `Path`, for example, a hexagonal Shape. Using `Path` for the `Shape` itself seems easy, but creating the tessellation seems tricky.

Here is the code I used for my `Hexagonal`:

```
struct Hexagon: Shape {
  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var path = Path()
    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
    let size = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2
    let angleOffset = CGFloat.pi / 6
    for i in 0..<6 {
      let angle = CGFloat(i) * CGFloat.pi / 3 + angleOffset
      let point = CGPoint(x: center.x + cos(angle) * size, y: center.y + sin(angle) * size)
      if i == 0 {
        path.move(to: point)
      } else {
        path.addLine(to: point)
      }
    }
    path.closeSubpath()
    return path
  }
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image: hexagonal-tesselation]

Comment: Hexagonal tessellation is the technical term, but googling for **"SwiftUI honey comb grid"** will give many more code examples. I like this one: https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disambiguate a foreach loop in Xcode with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230457/how-to-disambiguate-a-foreach-loop-in-xcode-with-swiftui)

Comment: Honestly **SwiftUI honey comb grid** term didn't came to mind while I was looking for a solution, thanks for pointing me at the right direction. The foreach looks similar but I'm thinking of a more dynamic solution like the first [link](https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/) you shared.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow the code to have a knowledge of the honeycomb structure then just laying out the hexagons is not too difficult. Here's an example using your Hexagon shape, with one tweak:

```swift
    let size = max(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2 // min -> max
```

```swift
struct Honeycomb: View {

    private let dimension: Int
    private let cellSideLength: CGFloat
    private let cellHeight: CGFloat
    private let cellWidth: CGFloat

    init(dimension: Int = 5, cellSideLength: CGFloat = 25) {
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.cellSideLength = cellSideLength
        self.cellHeight = cellSideLength * 2
        self.cellWidth = 2 *
        ((cellSideLength * cellSideLength) - ((cellSideLength / 2) * (cellSideLength / 2))).squareRoot()
    }

    private var aCell: some View {
        Hexagon()
            .foregroundColor(.mint)
            .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
            .overlay {
                Hexagon()
                    .stroke()
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: cellHeight / 2) {
            ForEach(0..<(dimension + 1) / 2, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<dimension, id: \.self) { _ in
                        aCell
                    }
                }
                .overlay {
                    if i > 0 {
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0..<dimension - 1, id: \.self) { _ in
                                aCell
                            }
                        }
                        .offset(y: -cellHeight + (cellSideLength / 2))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Honeycomb]